# <Android> Strange behaviour of "onListItemClick(...)" convenience method

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listfragment

I am implementing a fragment in my program that inherits from "ListFragment". This is because I am planning to show a list of items.

I created an adapter and called the convenience method "setListAdapter(ListAdapter)" to set the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    (...)

    ArrayAdapter<MyClass> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<MyClass>(getActivity(),
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                    mMyClass);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now I decided to respond to the user touching any of the views. I achieved that by overriding the ListFragment's convenience method, *onListItemClick(...)*:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Note the simplicity of this code: I am just changing that view's background color to a green color. I decided to run the code on my Android 4.4.2 phone and found a really strange behaviour:

**The view's background color DO change to a green color. But... not only that view's background color but also other (randomly chosen?) views way down in the list.**

Let's say I have 100 views (from 0 to 99) in my ListView. If I click on the View#0, not only that view's background color will change but also the background color from View#13, View#26, View#39, ... View#91 - they are equally distributed. But why?

And if I were to scroll down through the List at a high speed (moving my finger really fast, the views passing by extremely fast) then the views I mentioned before would be white again, while others would be green.

You can try this this at home and see what happens.

Any logical explanation for this? The [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) explicitly says that the onListItemClick's **v** parameter is:

> The view that was clicked within the ListView

Thanks

Comment: ListView recycles its Views. In your list of 100 items, there are only about 13 or 14 Views in the ListView, judging by the numbers you've given. When you, e.g., scroll down, and a View goes off-screen from the top, that View then moves to the bottom, and is one of the next Views to appear. If you've changed some attribute of that View that the Adapter doesn't handle, then it will retain that attribute after recycling. An ArrayAdapter only sets the text on a TextView, so it will never reset the View's background color. You'll need to implement a custom Adapter.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM., clear and superb explanation. I have two questions, though:

1) If I were to pass through the list items really quickly (move my finger really fast through the ListView) then the aforementioned views which background color was changed, will return white, while others will turn into a green color. Why?

2) I though I could modify views' properties through appropriate overriding of the convenience method "onListItemClick". Why can't I use this method to change the background color and need to use a custom Adapter instead?

Thanks again (cannot upvote don't know why)

Comment: 1) A ListView does quite a bit of optimization to make its scrolling appear smooth. When you fling quickly through the list, it may decide that some View updates and displays can be dropped, making the colors "jump around". 2) Ideally, you should be changing only the underlying data list to make changes to a ListView. The Adapter should handle setting attributes on the Views in its `getView()` method to ensure that each View's attributes are set according to the corresponding item in the data list.